# Increase and decrease the number using addEventListener keydown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a program that adds or subtracts a unit to `count` by pressing the up and down keys on the keyboard.
The problem is that the program does not work properly. When you press the key, look at the console, which runs several times, while each time you press the key, it only has to run once.
This is a problem that crashes after pressing the up or down buttons a few times, please help

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        setCount(count + 1);
        console.log(count);
        break;
      case 40:
        setCount(count - 1);
        console.log(count);
        break;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an event handler every time the component is rendered. The component is re-rendered whenever the state changes. It's an exponential loop, hence your application "crashes".

- Use `useEffect` to attach the event listener once the component is mounted and remove it again once the component is unmounted.
- Provide a callback to `setCount` to access the current count.

```
export default function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyDownCallback = function (e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          setCount((count) => count + 1);
          break;
        case 40:
          setCount((count) => count - 1);
          break;
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[See demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-chandrasekhar-1v5vcm?file=/src/App.js)

**Documentation**

- [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had another question, if we have an object instead of a number and we just want to increase and decrease the top, how should we write?                                        `const [count, setCount] = useState({ top: 0, left: 20 });`

Comment: @goodboy `setCount(({top, ...count}) => ({...count, top: top + 1}))` or something similar.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried this method but it did not work

Comment: @goodboy See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-chandrasekhar-1v5vcm?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Well each time your component re-renders, it attaches that event listener again and again and calls setCount too many times and re-renders component too many times. Therefore your program falls into infinite loop.
I think you should try useEffect and useLayoutEffect hooks.

**Edit**

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleUpdateCount = React.useCallback(
    (value) => setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + value),
    [setCount]
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const keyDownCallback = (e) => {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          handleUpdateCount(1);
          break;
        case 40:
          handleUpdateCount(-1);
          break;
        default:
          console.log("default");
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);
  }, [handleUpdateCount]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In these way, we prevent from extra re-renders.

And about useLayoutEffect, this hook runs given callback after all DOM mutations,
But according to official React documentation, We should tend to use useEffect as possible.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score -1):

You have to put  `document.addEventListener` in an `useEffect` or it will add an event listener each time component re-render

```
useEffect(() => {
   document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        setCount(count + 1);
        console.log(count);
        break;
      case 40:
        setCount(count - 1);
        console.log(count);
        break;
    }
  });
}, [])
```

Comment: You've closed over the original value of `count` so that won't have the desired effect either.

Comment: You've also forgotten to remove the event listener when the component unmounts.