# SetState(state+1) returns double the amount plus one in react

Tags: reactjs, setstate, codepen

I am trying to use a React function component to have a number increment + 1 on keydown but instead of increasing by one (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5) it returns it doubles the number and then increases by on (i.e. 1,3,7,15,31). How Do I get this to react correctly?

```
   const Display = (props) => {
      return( 
        <div id="display">{props.text}</div>
      )
    }

const App = () => {
  [displayText, setDisplayText] = React.useState(0);

  window.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
     setDisplayText(displayText + 1)
  })
   
  return (

   <div class="container">
     <Display text={displayText} /> 
   </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: You should be adding the event listener inside a `useEffect` hook and also, keep in mind that states updates are asynchronous operations, so if you want to modify the state based on a previous value, you should use the callback version of `setState` function. `setDisplayText(prev => prev + 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has already been answered here:
[Increase and decrease the number using addEventListener keydown in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220053/increase-and-decrease-the-number-using-addeventlistener-keydown-in-react)

**CODE**

```
export default function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyDownCallback = function (e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          setCount((count) => count + 1);
          break;
        case 40:
          setCount((count) => count - 1);
          break;
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the react strict mode from index.js file to see the correct results.Its that simple.
this error is caused due to strict mode.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you call setState in a react component, it triggers a re-render of that updated states component, and all the subsequent children of that component.

In your example, you're attaching an event listener to the window object, and calling setState whenever the client presses a key. This can cause inconsistencies in the number rendered in your  component, and the actual value of the count state.

To really understand the difference, you can try console logging the value of the state and observing the differences shown in your  component, and what's being logged to the console.

Side-note: As a general rule of thumb with event listeners, you want to clean-up the event listeners so you don't have any unwanted side-effects in your component tree.

Here's a good article about [rendering in react](https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide)
And as always, [the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) are a good place to dive deeper on best practices and behaviors, cheers!